# Django wsgiref/handlers.py throws exception like always

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I'm doing some django TDD samples following this article http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/tutorial/1/.

But when I try to run my testing I always got this problem,

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).get_response(request)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
return callback(request, **param_dict)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

I've tried Postgres and Sqlite3, the same output tortured me a lot.

Does anyone knows why I get this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because you're trying to render a template called `500.html` that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thank you @Aesthete . But I think that template is provided by django itself since I don't see any similar things in the tutorial. I guess this problem more or less related to my database configuration or the browser cache. But I'm not sure...

Comment: Have you read the [Write a 500 (server error) view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-500-server-error-view) section of the tutorial?

Comment: Hi @PedroRomano Thank you for your reminding, I added this 500.html page to my templates folder. And it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Aesthete , I added the 500.html. It did solved my problem. Thank you very much. But I'm just wondering why the server always throws this exception even though it doesn't loading a 500.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message states what went wrong.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

It seems you are missing the `500.html` file from wherever django is looking for your templates. Make sure this file exists.

I would assume that there is an internal error with your application, and Django is attempting to render it's `500 Internal Server Error` page, which is can't find. There is probably an earlier exception that Django caught before this one happened.